# Enable compiler compilation errors in Visual Studio when using #if Debug... #else

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to enable compilation errors in Visual Studio 2022 for code that is inside the `#else` clause of a `#if Debug...#else` conditional? I have a bit of code like so

```
#if Debug
    // do some stuff
#else
  // do some other stuff, but this code has compilation errors
#endif
```

My issue is when compiling the code in Visual Studio, it ignores the text inside the `#else` clause. Thus, if there are compilation errors they are not flagged as errors and compilation is successful, even if the code in the `#else` clause has errors.

This is routinely causing me to have compilation errors when building on the build server, because these compilations errors are not seen locally. I could remove the conditional and add them before check in, but that is a pain. There has to be a better way.

Google hasn't been much help. Any suggestion on how to handle this problem?

Comment: _"There has to be a better way."_ - yes: you can use the Solution Configuration drop-down in the Standard Toolbar to choose an MSBuild configuration that _does_ define those symbols.

Comment: Switch Debug To Release, to configuration combobox, and build solution

Comment: What specifically are you using the conditional compilation for? In my experience it is best to have debug and release builds as similar as possible, otherwise you run the risk of bugs that only appear in production, and that is often much more series.

Comment: I agree with @JonasH. Personally I would prefer to branch like this using configuration, allowing any code issues to be caught during dev/test. Ideally you would have (unit) tests around all your code anyway!

Comment: @JonasH It is for connecting to Azure BlobStorage.  When debugging we use azure creds through visual studio, otherwise we use app.config settings.  They exist as different types, and added to a list, so we need to dynamically initiate these values. So configurations won't work here, and unit tests wouldn't solve anything as the datatypes initiated is runtime dependent, not just config values.  I would prefer using HostEnvironment.IsDevelopement, but this is existing code, and the pattern exists everywhere already.  Thus changing it is not really an option.

Answer (score 1):

> There has to be a better way.

There is, the `Conditional` attribute:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void Trace() { /* ... */ }
```

Calling the `Trace` function above will be removed from code if its condition isn't defined, but it will still be parsed by the compiler for correctness.

Comment: It's another way, not necessarily a better way.  In particular, it doesn't give you an `else` opportunity (and it's the `else` path that is problematic here)

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from writing a second conditional function for release, if that's what you think is missing. Personally, in my 16 years as an avionics engineer, I've never needed conditionals and I've used exactly one `#if` to retarget a missing collection class (`BlockingCollection` I believe?) that is missing from .Net 5+ but is part of .Net Framework in a cross-framework library.

Comment: @Blindy Your experiences are atypical.

Comment: I am assuming you would need to call the trace() function somewhere. So how does it handle it when the method doesn't exist at runtime?

Comment: Exactly as you'd expect, no code is emitted!

Comment: It doesn't really solve my problem unfortunately, because this "pattern" exists everywhere already, and I am beholden to the devs that came before me.  However, I will give it a thumbs up for the effort, and I do think this is a better way.

Comment: "beholden to the devs that came before me" -- that's fair, but presumably the code that's already written compiles fine. The problem, I understand, is with code *you* write. As such, I still suggest you start using this pattern, but instead of replacing everything all at once, just replace the parts you touch when you touch them. Slow, gradual improvements that you can point to to show tangible benefits is the way to persuade others to follow your example.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend some way to specify configurations explicitly used for debugging. This might be command line parameters, the registry, or just a file that you put somewhere. If you add security sensitive things to this file it might be a good idea to use conditional compilation to ensure all settings have default values unless running in debug. I would at least consider making these settings accessible globally.

That would turn your conditional compilation into something like

```
if(DebugSettings.IsDebug){...}
else {...}
```

or

```
var credentials = DebugSettings.AzureCredentials ?? Settings.AzureCredentials;
```

if this for some reason is not possible you could try something like

```
#if DEBUG
    if(???){
        // do stuff
        return; // return to ensure other stuff is not run
    }
#endif
    // do some other stuff
```

The trick here is to make `???` something that is true, but the compiler cannot prove is true, otherwise you will get unreachable code errors.